# Why am I getting error: 'use of deleted function' with static atomic variable?

Tags: c++, class, atomic

I want to have a class with static variables that could be shared between threads, so I read somewhere that I can create thread-safe variables using `atomic`. So I have this in my *test.hpp* file:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <string>

class TestClass
{
public:
    static atomic<int32_t> test1;

    static atomic<uint16_t> test2;

    static atomic<bool> test3;

};
```

and this in my *test.cpp* file:

```cpp
#include <test.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

atomic<int32_t> TestClass::test1= 0;

atomic<uint16_t> TestClass::test2= 0;

atomic<bool> TestClass::test3= false;
```

But when I'm trying to compile this via cmake it gives me errors like this:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)’
 atomic<bool> TestClass::test3 = false;
```

and so on...
What could be reason of this? I found some similar questions on SO, but in this questions they were using their types for atomic variables and the solutions was just adding `noexcept` in their classes. But in my situation - I just use built-in types, what could be wrong?

Comment: the atomic variable cannot be copied so you need to initialize them by a public function set or ssomething.

Comment: @AnisBelaid It'll work in C++17 because the implicitly created `atomic<int32_t>` will not be copied/moved since that is elided. To make this work pre C++17: `atomic<int32_t> TestClass::test1{0};`
`atomic<uint16_t> TestClass::test2{0};`
`atomic<bool> TestClass::test3{false};`